# django email not being sent : ConnectionRefusedError WinError 10061

Tags: python, django, email

I am writing django application and trying to send email using it I have "Access to low security app" in gmail enabled and django setting are given below which I think are right. but I am still getting error as mentioned it title. I dont know the problem but I know I am not getting logged in to send email. 
Edit 1: I have made two changes first in settings.py and second in views.py in views.py I replaced email entered by user to mine(syedfaizan824@gmail.com) and settings.py DEFAULT_EMAIL_FROM is changed form testing@example.com to syedfaizan824@gmail.com

searched on internet and find out that gmail does not allow low security app to login by default but I turned it off in setting of gmail. find out that my email backend was wrong so made it right. fail silently is False.

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'syedfaizan824@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'syedfaizan824@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
```

views.py

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = contact(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
        organization = form.cleaned_data['organization']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        ref_code = form.cleaned_data['ref_code']
        plan = form.cleaned_data['plan']
        message = message + ref_code 
        send_mail(
            'from website' + name + " " + organization,
             message,
            'syedfaizan824@gmail.com',
            ['syedfaizan824@gmail.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
        print("sent")

    else:
        #print('something is wrong with forms!')
    return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)
```

Error message is ConnectionRefusedError WinError[10061]. and statement of error is : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. which means I am not getting logged in.

Comment: Are 'testing@example.com' and 'syedfaizan824@gmail.com' on the same Gmail account? Are these linked somehow?

Comment: No I think that when someone sees website and tries to contact he provide some email if the email field is not provided that from email is used from DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL although I have tried setting it to syedfaizan824@gmail.com which is my account and I am trying to send email from and to this account with entered information.

Comment: I have edited the question and views.py and settings.py according to your comment Matthew Gaiser.

Comment: Besides that, your settings.py looks exactly like mine. 
```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'
```

Comment: Does it work when you try the console email backend? EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

Comment: Yes it works on console

Comment: This is a cliche, but you have checked that the password is correct? Its' probably not that, so are you using a personal firewall or a VPN?

Comment: No firewall or vpn. I checked password this is right.

Answer (score 3):

change 
`EMAL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'`
to 
`EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'`

You are missing the 'I' character in the word 'EMAIL'